# add remove input not work in edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work with this code for add/remove input:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var MaxInputs = 2; //maximum extra input boxes allowed
  var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
  var AddButton = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

  var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
  var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text box added

  //on add input button click
  $(AddButton).click(function(e) {
    //max input box allowed
    if (x <= MaxInputs) {
      FieldCount++; //text box added ncrement
      //add input box
      $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_' + FieldCount + '"/> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a></div>');
      x++; //text box increment

      $("#AddMoreFileId").show();

      $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");

      // Delete the "add"-link if there is 3 fields.
      if (x == 3) {
        $("#AddMoreFileId").hide();
        $("#lineBreak").html("<br>");
      }
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    if (x > 1) {
      $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
      x--; //decrement textbox

      $("#AddMoreFileId").show();

      $("#lineBreak").html("");

      // Adds the "add" link again when a field is removed.
      $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");
    }
    return false;
  })

});
```

My Code worked in action For add input page ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Weyb/1/))

Now in Edit page I need to work with save(default) input, But my code not work and i cant remove save(default) input and i cant see remove link ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Weyb/122/))

How do fix this?!

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: First, you need to write something in your a tag for see the link....

Comment: @KalpeshRajai: which part of my question?!

Comment: @NewCod3r "Now in Edit page I need to work with save(default) input, But my code not work and i cant remove save(default) input and i cant see remove link"

Comment: Means you want the remove link on the side of the text boxes which is already added at the add page

Answer (score 2):

First write something here in your a tag, change this :

```
<a href="#" class="removeclass"></a>
```

To this :

```
 <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a>
```

And the length is wrong, what you want is number of inputsWrapper, then change this :

```
var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper");
```

To this :

```
var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper").children();
```

Comment: Not work true. remove default input then add new input then remove first input u see : all input removed!!! http://jsfiddle.net/7Weyb/124/

Answer (score 0):

As @A. Rossi said, you need to add a text in the `<a>` tag.
Also, the value of your `x` var is wrong.
See a working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var MaxInputs = 2; //maximum extra input boxes allowed
  var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
  var AddButton = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

  var x = InputsWrapper.children().length; //initlal text box count
  var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text box added

  //on add input button click
  $(AddButton).click(function(e) {
    //max input box allowed
    if (x <= MaxInputs) {
      FieldCount++; //text box added ncrement
      //add input box
      $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_' + FieldCount + '"/> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a></div>');
      x++; //text box increment

      $("#AddMoreFileId").show();

      $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");

      // Delete the "add"-link if there is 3 fields.
      if (x == 3) {
        $("#AddMoreFileId").hide();
        $("#lineBreak").html("<br>");
      }
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function(e) { //user click on remove text

    if (x > 1) {
      $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
      x--; //decrement textbox

      $("#AddMoreFileId").show();

      $("#lineBreak").html("");

      // Adds the "add" link again when a field is removed.
      $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");
    }
    return false;
  })

});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}
a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #802727;
}
input {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -web-kit-border-radius: 4px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div id="InputsWrapper">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_1" value="">
      <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_1" value="">
      <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_1" value="">
      <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_1" value="">
      <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="AddMoreFileId">
    <a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" class="btn btn-info">Add field</a>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="lineBreak"></div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: i cant remove last three input?! u can?!